# How to match products to their description using a composite primary key in products collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am struggling to match products in a products collection with the product info collections where the products has a composite primary key in the products collection.  The product are assigned a description code which they can use to extract the description for the products. However, I cannot successfully get a match using the composite id. My goal is to generate two reports. The first report should generate the products with their descriptions. The second should generate a reports for products with no descriptions. i have included my attempt to match the products with no description inspired from a solution kindly provided by rickhg12hs. However, my attempt does not work with composite keys.

Here are the collections:

```json
     //products
      {
        "_id" : {
          "productId" : NumberLong(23300),
          "categoryId" : NumberLong(7777)
        },
         "name" : "Musk Spray",
         "quantity" : 12333,
         "category" : "Fragrance",
         "price" : 122.99,
         "descriptionCode" : NumberLong(75),
         "brand" : "Musk Cologne",
         "updatedDate" : ISODate("2023-01-03T20:46:45.099+0000"),
         "createdDate" : ISODate("2023-01-03T20:46:45.099+0000"),
       }

      //product-info 
      {
         "_id" : ObjectId("572179b333316ab012),
         "productId": NumberLong(23300),
         "categoryId": NumberLong(7777),
         "descriptionCode" : NumberLong(75),
         "description" : 12333,
         "price" : 122.99,
         "description" : "Medium Range Cologne For Men",

        }
```

My attempt to find products without a description:

```json
           db.products.aggregate([
            {
               "$lookup": {
                  "from": "product-info",
                  "let": {
                   "productId": "$_id.productId",
                   "categoryId": "$_id.categoryId"
                  },
                  "as": "productInfo",
                  "pipeline": [
                   { // look for matches in productInfo
                    "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$and": [
                        {"$eq": ["$productId", "$$productId"]},
                        {"$eq": ["$categoryId", "$$categoryId"]}
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                 },
                 { // if matched, no need to return everything
                    "$project": {
                    "_id": 1
                    }
                }
                 ]
                }
             },
             { // match when no productInfo found
               "$match": {
                  "$expr": {
                  "$eq": [{"$size": "$productInfo"}, 0]
                  }
                }
              },
              { // output requested fields
               "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "productId": 1,
                "categoryId": 1
               }
             }
          ])
```

Comment: That product-info sample doc has 2 description fields

Comment: I tested that query in the playground with a minor tweak to the projection, it seems to work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GmNxQunu2Eo